# how can I convert flash game to windows

Tags: windows, flash

I have a question about publishing a Flash game to Windows (`.exe`) like how a Flash game can be published for Android (`.apk`) using Adobe Animate CC.

Is this possible or not? I need the method

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible or not?

Yes it's possible. The manual tells you how...

**Option 1**: Publish as a Projector (Windows `.exe`) instead of as SWF.
https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/animate/using/exporting-projector-files.html

**Option 2**: Create a standard AIR app (not using "AIR for Android" menu option).
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b21ec24feb12478b70aff-8000.html
Check out the last section called : **Package the application**.

Comment: hello thanks but i didn't this i need to publish in developer windows store

Comment: Under your tags `windows` and `flash` there is an [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56080486/edit) button. Use it to add any **important** information that others need to know about answering your Question correctly. Be exact about what you mean, don't wait 2 weeks to change the meaning of your Question.

Comment: What have you [**tried from research**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&source=hp&ei=nO3qXPukIOPjkgX6qKDoDg&q="adobe+air"+publish+to+"windows+store") that isn't working but you feel it was closest to achieving your goal? Maybe we can fix your effort.

Comment: thanks for this information ... maybe have you idea to help me thanks